# FORFILES file not found

Tags: batch-file, cmd, sqlcmd

A file specified in the /c parameter of a FORFILES command in my batch file is not being located.

```
FORFILES /p "%CSV_Path%" /m "*.csv" /c "cmd /c SQLCMD -S %db_server% -d %db% -E -i scripts\LoadStationCsv.sql -o LoadStationCsv.log -v TempTable = ##Dayparts CsvPath = @PATH"
```

SQL CMD shows the following error:

> Sqlcmd: Error: Error occurred while opening or operating on file
>   scripts\LoadStationCsv.sql (Reason: The system cannot find the path 
>   specified).

Executed from the command line, the SQLCMD runs with the parameters above. scripts/LoadStationCsv.sql file exists.

Comment: Have you tried using an absolute path to scripts\LoadStationCsv.sql?

Comment: Yes, full path works. I'm interested in the reason relative path does not.

Comment: It's probably because when you start CMD, it's probably executing in its own environment, which means its current directory wouldn't necessarily be where you issued the command.